# Считывание из EditText в ListView, через контекстное меню удаляем из ListView.Crash

Tags: android, listview, java

Задача:считывание из `editText`, перевод в `ListView`, по выделею элемента появляется контекстное меню с возможностью выбора-удалить.
через `OnItemClickListener` все нормально удаляет, не понимаю почему через `onContextItemSelected` происходит ошибка..помогите, пожалуйста

```
package com.example.todolist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ToDoListActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;
    ArrayList <String> todoItems;
    TextView myText;
    ArrayAdapter aa;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView myListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        final EditText myEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
        final ArrayList<String> todoItems=new ArrayList<String>();
        final TextView myText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
        aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,todoItems);
        myListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        myListView.setAdapter(aa);
        registerForContextMenu(myListView);

        //Считывание из editText в ListView
        myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
                if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    if((keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){
                        todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
                        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        myEditText.setText("");
                        return true;

                    }
                return false;
            }
        });

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position,
                    long id) { 

                        //final TextView myText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);   
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) itemClicked).getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        myText.setText(((TextView) itemClicked).getText());
                        todoItems.remove(position);
                        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

        });    
    } 
    @Override
       public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.add(0,CM_DELETE_ID,0,"delete");
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        // menu.add("Red");
        }
     @Override  
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
          // получаем инфу о пункте списка
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
          // удаляем Map из коллекции, используя позицию пункта в списке
          todoItems.remove(acmi.position);
          // уведомляем, что данные изменились
          aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
          return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
      }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.to_do_list, menu);
        //return true;
          menu.add("menu1");
          menu.add("menu2");
          menu.add("menu3");
          menu.add("menu4");
          return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Добавил логи:

```
W/dalvikvm(1009): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a4fb90)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1009): Process: com.example.todolist, PID: 1009
E/AndroidRuntime(1009): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.example.todolist.ToDoListActivity.onContextItemSelected(ToDoListActivity.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2619)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3808)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process(1009): Sending signal. PID: 1009 SIG: 9
```

Comment: @Larsen, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора. 
не забывайте ставить более общие метки - android,java наверное в данном случае

Comment: спасибо,впервой тут,сейчас все отредактирую

Comment: А чего логи ошибки не прикрепил ?
В ~90% ошибку можно там найти быстрее чем в коде)

Comment: @Billy Milligan, Ни разу не смотрел их-сразу тестировал на телефоне..извините,если что не так с ними-переделаю

Comment: @Billy Milligan, блин,я с этим уже два дня борюсь\\

Comment: Вы добавляете текст в локальный `todoItems`, а удалять пытаетесь из глобального, который у Вас даже не инициализирован - отсюда и NullPointer.
`final ArrayList<String> todoItems=new ArrayList<String>();`
замените на     
`final ArrayList<String> todoItems = this.todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();`     
либо     
`todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 1):

Из комментария @woesss:

Вы добавляете текст в локальный `todoItems`, а удалять пытаетесь из глобального, который у Вас даже не инициализирован - отсюда и NullPointer.

```
final ArrayList<String> todoItems=new ArrayList<String>();
```

замените на

```
final ArrayList<String> todoItems = this.todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
```

либо

```
todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
```